# Remove list item where it matches text

Tags: c#, list

Below I check to see if a text value is in LstNewItems and NOT in ListOfItemsToControl. This works fine. Within the if statement i want to remove the row from LstNewItems that matches the text value? lstNewItems is a list.

```
string name = rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

if (MyGlobals.lstNewItems.Any(x => x.sItemName == name) && !MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Any(y => y.sItemName == name)) 
{
   //Remove the row from LstNewItems that matches the text value
}
```

Comment: If `lstNewItems` is a `List`, you can use `lstNewItems.RemoveAll(predicate)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what the collection actually is.
If it's a generic `List<>` you can do:

```
MyGlobals.lstNewItems.RemoveAt(i);
```

Tell me if it works otherwise give us the exact type of the collection.

Remember you can't modify a collection inside a loop that uses it as an enumeration. Like this:

```
foreach (var x in MyGlobals.lstNewItems)
{
    MyGlobals.lstNewItems.Remove(x); // will throw an InvalidOperationException
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (MyGlobals.lstNewItems.Any(x => x.sItemName == rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() && !MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Any(y => y.sItemName == rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()))) 
{
    MyGlobals.lstNewItems.RemoveAll(item => item.sItemName == rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This would only work if `lstNewItems` is a list. But you didn't mention its type in the question.

Comment: Apologies - i thought it was clear from the question and tags but i have updated the question now.